# How can I set the Taborder for the usercontrols in the Content Control of WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a window in which two contentcontrol, in which i'm loading the usercontrol at runtime,
I need to set the tab order for the user controls in the ContentControl1 and ContentControl2?
How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359758/setting-tab-order-in-wpf

Comment: i need to set the tab order for Controls in the UserControl which has been loaded at runtime.. i have already tried the solution given in that thread but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation and KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex to achieve this.

Example :

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Head}" x:Name="HeadCtrl" Height="50" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource VectorTemplate}"/>

 <DataTemplate x:Key="VectorTemplate">
    <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="-1">
         <Button Content="{Binding Path=X}" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" ></Button>
         <Button Content="{Binding Path=Y}" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" ></Button>
    </StackPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: But i'm having two content controls, i need to tab through both content controls. And the challenge is the contentcontrol1 is populated with a Usercontrol having textboxes at runtime and The content control2 is populated with buttons at compile time. I not using any datatemplate. I'm very new to WPF help me pls

Comment: Are the number of textboxes in usercontrol constant? if yes then you can specify KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex while creating the textboxes and buttons. It could be in any form. The challenge would be if the number of your textboxes is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand is to set the Tab order of the usercontrol that you are adding at runtime. How about doing this:

```csharp
 var usercontrol = new UserControl1();
 usercontrol.TabIndex = 0;
 ContentControl1.Content = usercontrol;
```

Comment: ya.. but wht abt the textboxes inside the usercontrol?

Comment: you can set it in usercontrol itself or give that textbox a Name in xaml e.g. <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="MyText"></TextBox> and than you can set it from code also like usercontrol.myTextBox.TabIndex = 0;