# wpf - how to keep a control from being selected through tabbing

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to prevent a control from receiving focus when tabbing through elements?

I'd like to do this in XAML.

Here's an example, where I'd like to keep the second textbox from receiving focus when tabbing through controls:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="tb1"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Name="tb2"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359758/setting-tab-order-in-wpf

Comment: @Wamadahama yep that gets it, although that question's title doesn't indicate this is even covered. I'll vote to mark this as a duplicate.